# In ME1 how do you skip a conversation, but not choose an answer?

Tags: mass-effect

I read the subtitles a whole lot faster than the people talk in Mass Effect 1, and I've played the game through once already.

So I'm looking for a way to **skip a cutscene without accidentally choosing an answer**.

Currently, I'm using <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> to skip the dialog; however, since spacebar also selects the dialog option, pressing spacebar one time too many can result in random dialog choices.

Comment: I'd like to have the same info for the XBox 360... This is plain annoying : I already finished the game and know the data, but quitting a conversation is both annoying and dangerous (won't some potential choices will be lost?)

Comment: @paercebal: removed the `pc` tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No way to do it. The only way is to slowly move the mouse into the neutral part of the wheel. This way most of the time you can skip it without much consequences.

Comment: :/ Ok, thanks. I thought that might be the case.

Answer (score 4):

There is a way via a Coalesced.ini mod, for use with Mod Manager.
I'm not sure it can be made to work on xbox - but if you have a PC, you can just use the save as option of the mod manager.

This is for PC version, xbox will have a different bind name - just take a peek in the Mod Manager.
Note: Each +/- is one line.

```
[SFXGame.SFXGameModeConversation]  
-Bindings=( Name="SpaceBar",Command="PC_ConvSkip")  
;; This way it won't skip first entry in the next conversation at times and doesn't select  
+Bindings=( Name="SpaceBar",  Command="set BioConversation m_bSkipRequested true | OnRelease set BioConversation m_bSkipRequested false")  
;; If you want to keep this old bind just in case  
+Bindings=( Name="N",Command="PC_ConvSkip")
```

Comment: Note to all who happen upon this: This is for Mass Effect 2 (and 3). The question was about Mass Effect **1**, which did _not_ have `Coalesced.ini`.