# Change a Mass Effect keybinding for vault?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-2

I find it very annoying that the run, hide, and vault are all the same button. I can't tell you how many times I have been trying to unhide so I could backpedal to a different cover position, when because I had the joystick slightly pressed I instead vaulted at the attacker and got killed.

Is there a way to change the key bindings so I stop killing myself because of the awkward control interface?

I realize that there is probably different answers for each system. My specific situation is for Xbox, but I assume the other console owners have the same problem since the bindings are the same.

In [this answer regarding keybindings for conversation skipping w/o choosing a response](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/14774/1134), there was mention of only being able to do this for PC by modding the config files. Does the same apply, and if so, if I get the PC version, what are config settings I must change?

I guess this would be most applicable to ME3 since it recently came out, but I still had the same problems in the other games, so the answer could apply to all of them, if that's possible.

Comment: It's probably impossible for consoles. I don't believe it was possible to change controls via config editing in ME2, so it's probably impossible in ME3 as well.

Comment: I wanted to shoot whomever thought it was a good idea to make "use" and "run" the same button in ME2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot customize the control layout for consoles the way you describe. No such options exist in the game options, nor does any reference to customizing controls exist in the console manuals: http://help.ea.com/article/mass-effect-3-manuals

Here is the controller options screen in the Xbox 360 version:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Download something called the ME2INIFIXER, then download notepad++.

GO into your main game folder, biogame, config,pc, cooked and open the INI inside with Notepad++ (if you use a regular text editor it will f--- it up so dont)

Using your find options you can find the keybinds under [SFXGame.SFXGameModeDefault]

Now you can add things, but i cannot for the life of me find where MY binds are saved... but there are some handy things you can do like add a crouch command

Bindings= ( Name="LeftControl", Command="set SFXPawn_Player bWantsToCrouch true | OnRelease set SFXPawn_Player bWantsToCrouch false" )

or change the fov (like you did with me1)

Now from the looks of it ME2 and ME3 work the same way so, hopefully that will work out.